# Проблема с SQL-запросом.

Tags: скрипт, mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE course (
    course_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lecturer_id INT NOT NULL,
    start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    hours INT NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    cost INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (lecturer_id) REFERENCES lecturer(lecturer_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE course_student (
    course_id INT NOT NULL,
    student_id INT NOT NULL,
    mark INT NULL,
    review VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(course_id, student_id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES course(course_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student(student_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Здравствуйте всем! Выше представлены две таблицы. У меня возникла проблема: не могу написать SELECT-запрос, который помог бы мне, имея student_id, вывести все курсы co статусом 'enrollment', на которые студент с данным student_id не записан, т.е. нет записей в таблице course_student, связывающей student_id с искомыми курсами.

Спасибо огромное заранее!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from course c where status = 'enrollment' and not exists(select cs.course_id from course_student cs where cs.course_id = c.course_id and cs.student_id = ?);
```

или

```
select c.* from course c left join course_student cs on c.course_id = cs.course_id and cs.student_id = ? where c.status = 'enrollment' and cs.course_id is null;
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!
До этого у меня было нечто похожее, но намного тупее и с третьим студентом начинало "дублировать" курсы =)

SELECT * FROM course
LEFT JOIN course_student ON course_student.course_id = course.course_id
WHERE status = 'enrollment' AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM course_student 
WHERE course_student.course_id = course.course_id AND student_id = ? );

Голова ночью совсем не работала. Спасибо, что сохранили мне немного времени своим ответом =)